# discord & multiprocessing deadman switch python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

i was trying to make this logic so if i got a message on discord that contains "911" it destroys the script or calls some functions and stop the timer
im facing a lot of errors and i can't think ofa proper way to do it ...

any help ?

```
from time import sleep
import discord
import multiprocessing

client = discord.Client()
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
sign = manager.boolean(False)

def Timer(sign):
    for second in range(15):
        if sign == True:
            print("bloooock")
            break
        if sign == False:
            print("passsssss")
            sleep(1)
def discord_message(client, sign):
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print('Logged on as', client)
    async def on_message(message):
        messageContent = message.content
        if len(messageContent) > 0:
            if messageContent == str("911"):
                sign = manager.bool(True)
    client.run('###')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=Timer, args=(sign,))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=discord_message, args=(client, sign,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set a variable within a function, it will default to the local scope. Look at this example:

```python
a = 1
def f(): a = 2
f()
print(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P1HBVsGQKyU1TSFNQ9NKAcQ14gIyuQqKMvNKNBI1//8HAA)

This will output 1.

```python
a = 1
def f(): print(a); a = 2
f()
print(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P1HBVsGQKyU1TSFNQ9NKoaAoM69EI1HTWgEkYcQFFOSCif3/DwA)

This will actually error, because since you set `a = 2` within the function `f`, `a` becomes a local variable so `print(a)` errors because it isn't defined at that point.

To get around this, put `global a` at the top of your function. In your case, do `global sign` inside `def on_message` like so:

```py
def discord_message(client, sign):
    ...
    async def on_message(message):
        global sign
        ...
```

Right now, when `sign = manager.bool(True)` is being set, it isn't affecting the global variable `sign` which the `Timer` is reading.

Also, I think you need to add `@client.event` above `async def on_message` as well.

Comment: thanks it works so well :)